# Getting Started on building electron apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

so I have built a simple electron app but don't really know how to make it do anything on the server side (the whole reason of using electron other than the cool window)  I was wondering if I would have to use something like socket.io but I figured there was a better way of doing this here is my code for now

index.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const io = require('socket.io');
const app = electron.app; // Module to control application life.
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow; // Module to create native browser window.
var mainWindow = null;


app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + 'masterstyle.css');
    mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});

io = socket;
```

and here is the HTML it loads

```
<head>
    <title>Rex Serial Manipulator</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="tab">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'basic-window')">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'advanced-window')">Advanced</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'monitor-window')">Monitor</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="main-content-div" class="main-content-div">
        <div id="basic-window" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;">
            <center>
                <p>Basic Serial Control
                    <p>
                        <div id="main-controls-div">
                            <form id="form-1">
                                <input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>

                            </form>
                            <form id="form-2">
                                <input type="text" id="serial-value2" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send"></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" class="plus-button" value="+" onclick="addButton()">
                        </input>
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="advanced-window" class="tabcontent">

        </div>

        <div id="monitor-window" class="tabcontent">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
<script>
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }


    (function($) {
        var controls = [{
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            }, {
                textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
            },


        ];

        function showMessages() {
            var controlsDiv = $('#main-controls-div');
            controlsDiv.html('');
            controls.forEach(function(control) {
                controlsDiv.append(
                    control.textField + '&nbsp' +
                    '<button class="delete" row="' +
                    controls.indexOf(control) + '">Send</button><br></br>');
            });
        } //showMessages()


        // document.ready()
        $(function() {
            showMessages();
            $('#addmessage').on('click', function() {
                console.log('hi');
                controls.push({
                    textField: '<input type="text" id="serial-value1" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>'
                });
            });
        });
    }(jQuery));

    function addButton() {
        var serialValNum = 3;
        var div = document.getElementById('main-controls-div');
        div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" class="serial-value-txt-box"></input>&nbsp<input type="submit" value="Send"></input></br></br>'
        serialValNum++
    }
</script>
<style>
    .plus-button {
        background-color: #2ecc71;
        height: 30px;
        width: 225px;
        border: 0px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    ul {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: #252526;
    }

    ul.tab li {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
        background: #252526;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    /* Style the links inside the list items */

    ul.tab li a {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #2ecc71;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-family: helvetica;
    }
    /* Change background color of links on hover */

    ul.tab li a:hover {
        background-color: #2c2c2c;
    }
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */

    ul.tab li a:focus,
    .active {
        background-color: #1e1e1e;
    }
    /* Style the tab content */

    .tabcontent {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        display: none;
        border-top: none;
        background: #1e1e1e;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background: #1e1e1e;
    }

    .main-content-div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 48px;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

so how would i be able to press a button and it call a function on the index.js side :)

Answer (score 0):

Electron is not a server, it's just Node.js based program that spawn child process to render WebUI(called renderer process).

Electron itself called main process, and create new BrowserWindow object from here will creates new renderer process that you can actually see the browser.

Electron is working by Node.js, so you can run the Web server theoritically, but I don't recommend it, server must be seperated.

Just create new Node application to make WebServer + Socket.io, and install Socket.io-client into your Electron App, now that will works.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to call a few methods/functions in main process, maybe you can use `ipc`([ipcMain](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/) and [ipcRenderer](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/))

You can use them to communicate between the main process and renderer processes.